# What is the meaning of this code? Related with polymorfism

Tags: java, polymorphism, radix, derived-class, println

```
public class Base {
   public String className() {
      return "Base";
   }
}

public class Derived extends Base {
   @Override
   public String className() {
      return “Derived”;
   }
   public void testCalls() {
      Base base = (Base)this;
      out.println("Through this: " + this.className());
      out.println("Through base: " + base.className());
      out.println("Through super: " + super.className());
   }
}
```

Where came **this** and **super**? Also why it's **out.println** and not **System.out.println**?

Comment: Read a couple of more pages of the book you took this example from. I'm sure they would be explaining each and every bit of it.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 3):

- [`this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) is a reserved keyword that means the object which is performing
  the method/constructor.
- [`super`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) is also a reserved word, that refers to the "parent" of the current class.
- It's `out.println` because somebody probably used [`static import`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) on `System` (this is a bad practice usually, so you better avoid it).

Answer (score 1):

You have to read some basics on Object Oriented Programming and Java.

- `this` refers to the current instance
- `super` refers to the super class of the current instance

`out` without more context (e.g. a `import static java.lang.System.out;`) won't compile.

The first 2 will print "Derived" because of polymorphism and virtual method invocation: casting the reference to `this` does not change the nature of the instance which is of `Derived` type. The third prints "Base", because `super.className()` refers explicitly to the method defined in the `Base` class.

Comment: `out without more context won't compile.` it will, with static import. http://ideone.com/5vhYPl

Comment: Well, it was exactly my point ;), you need some more _information_ like a _static import_.

Answer (score 0):

So, when you "extend" a class you basically say "I want this new class to be exactly like that class, but with everything in this class added on as well" (this is overly simplified and will be explained further and learn more about polymorphism).

So, the extended class has to call "super()" as the first thing in it's constructor, which just lets the class that it is extending know to call it's constructor before the newer class can finish (or even get past starting) it's own construction.

So basically, when you extend a class, you need to call super() as the first line of the new class's constructor.

As for "this", it refers to the current instantiation of the class it is in. This is a pretty foundational concept to Java (and really a lot of languages). So definitely dig into this one if you don't understand it.

A simple example of "this":

```
public class OurClass {
    private int aClassVar;

    public OurClass(int aClassVar) {
        this.aClassVar = aClassVar;
    }
}
```

So, in the code block above, when we instantiate with "new OurClass(3)" we have to use the "this.aClassVar" so that Java knows that we mean the classes aClassVar and not the aClassVar in the method's parameters (because they have the same name). This happens because this refers to the current class instantiation.

An example of super():

```
public class OurClass {
    private int aClassVar;

    public OurClass(int aClassVar) {
        this.aClassVar = aClassVar;
    }

    public String aRandomMethod() {
        return "Papa class!";
    }
}


public class OurNewClass extends OurClass{

    public OurNewClass() {
        super(4);
        System.out.println(this.aRandomMethod());
    }
}
```

So, using the code above, you can see we use the "this" keyword, but also extended our old class, creating a new class based on the old one. When we call super(4) it calls the constructor from OurClass, giving it the parameter that it's expecting (an integer, in this case: 4). It then stores that integer where the constructor tells it to and finishes building the base class, then the rest of the constructor for OurNewClass can finish and print out it's aRandomMethod() string.

Hope this helps!